# How to configure apt to ignore if there are installed packages with unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt

Some applications deb packages have irrelevant dependencies which are actually not needed to be met for the application to work. For example Linux Process Explorer depends on `schedutils` which does not exist while the functionality it is meant to provide is included in some other package (`util-linux` AFAIK) if I understand it correctly. So, in cases like that the application can be installed with `dpkg --force-all -i` and function correctly, but this will break apt-get - it will refuse to work any more as far as a package with an unmet dependency is installed. I know `equivs` can be used to create a fake  package but this seems a way too clumsy: can't the check just be disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the check can't be disabled. [It's been requested, and it won't happen.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=548661)

Aside from faking a package for the dependency, your other options are:

- edit `dpkg`'s status file (see [this SU post](https://superuser.com/a/815371/334516), [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/a/506993/229499)) (**risky!**)
- edit the .deb file (see top voted answer on [the SF post](https://serverfault.com/a/383958/229499) linked above)